# EPIserver CMS Install a sample site

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, episerver, .net-framework-version

I am new to episerver CMS. I need to install a sample site on EPiserver CMS. I am getting an error when I create a new website based on the Episerver Alloy sample site.

[image]

I have gone through the installation based on the tutorial from the below link https://world.episerver.com/documentation/Items/Installation-Instructions/installing-episerver/#CMS

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

Check the documentation, it says

- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6.1 or 4.7

**Note**: After 2015, Microsoft
   .NET Framework 4.5.0 and 4.5.1 are not supported. From CMS 11, 4.6.1
   is required.

- C# 5.0 or later compatible versions
- MVC 5.2.3

https://world.episerver.com/documentation/items/system-requirements/system-requirements---episerver/

Seems like if you are running to old .net version